# iOS Enterprise program: not able to install IPA file created using in-house provisioning profile on one of our device

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

We are using iOS enterprise account for distributing our iOS app. We are using the in-house distribution scheme of enterprise program.

As far as my knowledge, we don't need to install the in-house provisioning profile  in the targeted device. Also, I believe that we don't need to add the device UDID in iOS portal since it's an enterprise account. Please correct my last two statements if my knowledge is wrong.

I am creating the IPA file using the in-house provisioning profile only. But while installing the same on one of our devices (iPhone 5s), I am getting below error.

```
 "**A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.**"
```

I tried to install the same IPA file on another device (iPhone 4s). I have not installed the distribution provisioning profile in that device also. And it's working fine there. So only I concluded that We don't need to install any provisioning profile on the device in case of iOS enterprise program.

Below is my provisioning profile from enterprise account which I am using.

[image]

I am not sure why this is happening. Please help me and let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Did you create a distribution Provisioning profile?

Comment: Yes. I am using a distribution profile. And please take note that this is an enterprise account. Not the standard iOS developer account. Please refer to the new screenshot which I attached to the question.

Comment: are you getting this while trying to install it using Xcode?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to install from Xcode organizer.

Comment: I can help you directly if you need.  I have worked with enterprise development for several organizations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a provisioning profile that is set for distribution.  This profile needs to be using a certificate that is installed on the Mac you want to create the archive from.  The profile gets installed along with the application.

You do not have to have the device added to the portal (only development devices need to be added).

One note - the profile will expire yearly.  You will have to publish at least one update every year to include an updated and renewed provisioning profile.

Here's some screenshots:

Keychain Access:
[image: Keychain]

---

Build Settings (Xcode):
[image: Build Settings]

---

Archive:
[image: Archive]

Comment: Thanks Eljay!!! But I am following everything correctly whatever you said above. I am using distribution version of provisioning profile and certificate. Both are from the same enterprise account also. The main point is I am able to install the IPA on other devices. It's not happening only on one device. I will be glad to seek your help. Please provide your valuable feedback.

Comment: Is there a difference in the iOS version on that one device as compared to the other ones?  What is the target version for the application?

Comment: Target version is iOS 5. And the device OS is iOS 7.0.6. So, I guess there should not be any problem with that. One more important information. Before few days, I was able to install all the builds on the same device. Not sure what change happened in the device. That was being used by other team members for last few weeks. Could you tell me if I can do something with the device settings as well.

Comment: Can you guess any clue?